# android.view.Inflate Exception, emulator says application has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android

I am new to android and using google map v2 for the 1st time by looking at android developer tutorials. getting exceptions and don't know what is wrong. Can someone help me out ?

### LOG CAT

```
03-12 22:00:01.678: D/AndroidRuntime(278): Shutting down VM
03-12 22:00:01.678: W/dalvikvm(278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception      (group=0x4001d800)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity      ComponentInfo{com.sameer.example.maps_example/com.sameer.example.maps_example.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.sameer.example.maps_example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  ... 11 more
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.sameer.example.maps_example-2.apk]
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at  android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
03-12 22:00:01.758: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  ... 19 more
```

### XML LAYOUT FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

### Java File

```
package com.sameer.example.maps_example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
 }
```

### Android Manifest

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sameer.example.maps_example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<permission
    android:name="com.sameer.example.maps_example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>


<uses-permission android:name="com.sameer.example.maps_example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="API_KEY"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What version of the emulator are you testing on?

Comment: I tried on 2 emulators;
1. Emulator for platform 2.2 API level 8
2. Emulator for platform 4.1 API level 16
if this answers your question ?

Comment: Okay, but which two? Which version of Android?

Comment: 1. Emulator for platform 2.2 API level 8

2. Emulator for platform 4.1 API level 16 if this answers your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing application for API V8 but you are using `MapFragment` and `Activity` classes.
instead you should use the `android-support-v4` library and use the `SupportMapFragment` and `FragmentActvity` classes.

To add the support library to the project you need to download it using the SDK Manager.
and then you can right click your project and chose Android Tools -> SupportLibrary.

Then extand your map Activity from FragmentActivity and make shure you are importing:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

in you XML file use the SupportMapFragment class instead of MapFragment, like so:

```
 <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say ;"Then extend your map Activity from FragmentActivity" and secondy i imported android.support.v4 into my libs folder is that okay ? or android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity is something else i need to import ? lastly do i need to make any changes in android manifest under uses sdk ???

Comment: Alright i get what you mean when you say extend your activity from fragment activity! just did that. Now my emulator is saying google services missing even though i have imported google play services. can you help me this as well ?

Comment: you are adding the google services in a wrong way, see this link: https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435 it's a blog post i wrote on how to add google maps to your application.

Comment: xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" gives a error that is Error parsing XML:unbound prefix

Comment: please open a new question with your current problem, you will get more attention that way. if I'm not mistaken this happens when you referencing the android-support-v4 in a wrong way, or you still didn't added the Google services library correctly. but again open a new post and you will receive help from all SO users and not only from me. if you can't find the problem try to go over this blog post i wrote from creating google map application: https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435